# Keras input shape mismatch error for multi-feature CNN classification model

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

Here is my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3,
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(14,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values,
          batch_size=4,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=2,
          validation_data=(X_test.values,y_test.values))
```

And error is:
`Error when checking input: expected conv1d_35_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (13166, 14)`

As suggested by other posts, I tweaked with flatten layer before output layer but that did not work.

My `X_train.values.shape` gives `(13166, 14)`
Any suggestion how should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape the `X_train.values` from `(13166, 14)` to `(13166, 14, 1)` as your input shape of CNN network is `(None, 14, 1)`.
This may solve your problem:

```
X_train.values.reshape([-1,14,1])
```